# Why was Amnon not punished by David for raping Tamar?

Tags: david, cultural-analysis, 2-samuel, genealogy, solomon

David is unwittingly involved in the set-up, by agreeing to Amnon's request to have Tamar make him some cakes. II Samuel 13:6,7.
He KNEW what happened next, and was very angry. II Samuel 13:21.
He did nothing for two full years. II Samuel 13:23.
The death of Amnon comforted him. II Samuel 13:23. *(I THINK that's what this verse means, but there may be some other meaning I'm not seeing.)*

Is it because Amnon was David's first-born son (II Samuel 3:2), and perhaps heir apparent?
With respect to the heir apparent, I'm not entirely at ease about that argument. So far, the Kingship has not followed bloodlines strictly:
Both Saul and David derived their crown from Samuel (I Samuel 10, I Samuel 16);
It took the intervention of Abner to put Ish-bosheth, the son of Saul, on the throne of Israel.
It sure was confusing when the kingship was actually transferred (II Kings 1). Chileab, David's second-born, is never mentioned after his birth is noted (II Sam 3).
Solomon, David's designated heir, was son number 10 from wife number 8, if I am recording things accurately.

So, I SUPPOSE the idea of the kingship passing to the oldest son could have been strongly favored, based on the traditions of other kingdoms, but was it strong enough to keep King David from disciplining Amnon for raping and rejecting Tamar?

Comment: I don't know. It does seem in character for David to avoid bloodshed of VIPs (he refused to kill Saul when he became an enemy).
Nathan also told him "This sword will never leave your house" after the Bathsheba incident. So David is responsible for inviting the evil into his house.

Comment: @Keegan Diggs: I think thats a good point. It seems that God punished David primarily through his children. The child born to him of Bathsheeba dies, the third born son Absolom rebels against him drives him from the city and sleeps with his concubines, his first born son rapes his daughter Tamar and is eventually killed. His son Adonijah attempted to usurp the thrown and was executed by his brother and heir Solomon. Interestingly though at the end of it all the woman David commited adultery with Bathsheeba is the lineage through which the future Kings like Solomon etc and eventually Jesus came

Comment: Why do you think he wasn't punished? Are you assuming everything David did in his life is recorded in the Bible? All we know is that the scriptures are silent on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

This comes after the episode where David commits adultery with Bathsheba and has her lawful husband killed in order to cover up his crime.

It is possible that David felt too compromised—because of his own failings—to impose the proper punishment.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not sure that was a valid excuse for David.  He still had certain parental responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It might be circuitous/tortuous reasoning but here goes:

1. David has adulterous sinful sexual relations with Bathsheba
2. Prophet Nathan confronts David about his sin
3. David feels remorseful, and therefore repents
4. Prophet Nathan does say God forgives David but there are still going to be consequences due to said sexual sin
5. David's eldest son, Amnon, rapes his half-sister, Tamar
6. David hears about the aforementioned rape, but can Only be angry because

   a) he feels hypocritical due to his own adulterous sinful sexual affair with Bathsheba

   b) also, David recollects that Prophet Nathan did still say that negative consequences would happen due to David's aforementioned sin

   c) all of them are his children, and it is sometimes difficult for a parent to
   resolve conflicts that are between his/her children because the parent loves all of them, and therefore, has difficulty siding with one over the other.

**Note:2 Samuel 13:20-22 gives an account of David's anger immediately after the story about Amnon raping Tamar. Let me explain, 2 Samuel 13:20-22 verse was mentioned immediately just after the story of Amnon raping Tamar, and then Tamar being in shame. Furthermore, only later on when we read 2 Samuel 13:23-38 gives account of Absalom's taking revenge by killing Amnon. Finally, as we continue to read past 2 Samuel 15 , we learn that Absalom leads a rebellion or coup d'etat against King David.**

Interesting Side Note: I suppose a better term to use to describe David's angry reaction would be the term "galling" because David might have felt caught in his own "web of hypocrisy"

> 2 Samuel 13:20-22
>
> 20 Then Absalom her brother said to her, “Has Amnon your brother been with you? But now keep silent, my sister, he is your brother; do
> not take this matter to heart.” So Tamar remained and was desolate in
> her brother Absalom’s house. 21 Now when King David heard of all these
> matters, he was very angry. 22 But Absalom did not speak to Amnon
> either good or bad; for Absalom hated Amnon because he had violated
> his sister Tamar.

Answer (score -1):

**Why was Amnon not punished by David for raping Tamar?**

There are two reasons that David took no action against the offender.

1/ No formal charges of accusation made -Deuteronomy 19:15

2/ Absalom  requested his sister to keep silent, he  also did not  speak to Amnon .  2 Samuel  13: 20,22

> 18 "Now she had on a [h]long-sleeved garment; for in this manner the
>   virgin daughters of the king dressed themselves in robes. Then his
>   attendant took her out and locked the door behind her. 19 Tamar put
>   [i]ashes on her head and tore her [j]long-sleeved garment which was on
>   her; and she put her hand on her head and went away, crying aloud as
>   she went."
>
> 20 "Then Absalom her brother said to her, “Has Amnon your brother been
>   with you? But now keep silent, my sister, he is your brother; do not
>   take this matter to heart.” So Tamar remained and was desolate in her
>   brother Absalom’s house.21 Now when King David heard of all these
>   matters, he was very angry. 22 But Absalom did not speak to Amnon
>   either good or bad; for Absalom hated Amnon because he had violated
>   his sister Tamar."

David was very angry, but in view that no formal charges of  accusation were made and in the absense of evidence, David  could not take any  action against the offender -(Read- Deut 19:15 below.)

Also you will note in verse 20 that Absalom requested his sister to keep silent, perhaps to save him and his  family unpleasant publicity.

Deuteronomy 19:15  (NASB)

> 15 “A single witness shall not rise up against a man on account of any
>   iniquity or any sin [a]which he has committed; on the evidence of two
>   or three witnesses a matter shall be confirmed."

Comment: Ouch. That means that although it was known that Amnon raped Tamar, no one was willing to testify. Is that due to the influence of Absalom?

Comment: Noted that two or three witnesses are required, but there is at least ONE case in which only the accuser is required: Deut 22:25-27, the case of an engaged girl raped in the field. She cries out, but there was no one to help her. The rapist is put to death, not the girl. Actually, I wonder if an expert in the law would say that this is the same circumstance Tamar was in; Amnon had taken pains to send all possible help (and all possible witnesses) away. NOT being a legal scholar, I can't offer a authoritative opinion.

Comment: Firstly your question I considered it to be a very good question, and I was  surprised to see later that it was down voted +1 . Although two or more  witnesses were required for an offence to stand, however if the accused admitted to  the offence then that was all that was required. It is obvious that since David new as well as Absalom, the rest of the family most likely knew as well, Tamar on the advise of her brother kept silent and did not lodge any charges.